# How to query for two strings in MondoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below is the schema for an array contacts. The contacts array has a field hashtag which is another array. 
I get the results when a user searches for a single hashtag - *openLove*. How to query when the user searches for *#openLove #Marriage* and expects contacts hash-tagged with *openLove* and *Marriage*?

```
"contacts" : [
    {
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "tell.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "latestTag",
            "anotherTag",
            "#hash",
            "openLove",
            "hellTwo",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    },
{
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "naveenpaul.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "latestTag",
            "anotherTag",
            "#hash",
            "marraige",
            "hellTwo",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    },
{
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "naveenpaul.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "polly",
            "tagger",
            "#hash",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you save all the hastags without the "#"?
One way can be you store without # and while finding you remove the # from the input which user have given..this way if you know the query it can work both ways, with and without #

Comment: And your contact array is within any document?

Comment: Yes, I'm saving the hashtags without the "#". Problem is not with storing the actual "#". I'm trying to get the results where two hashtags - openLove and Marriage are part of two diff contacts. And when user searches for them at the same time, the result should be those two hash-taggged contacts.

Comment: Did you try $elemMatch? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: Ok. from the document i felt that you are storing with #

Comment: You can use '$in' on the field hastags..along with the elemMatch projection..
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/

I guess if you combine these two, it can help you.

Comment: @AnirudhModi Yes, I think that's the proper way to do it

Comment: What is your expected  result?

Comment: [Embedding a potentially infinite list is the root of all evil](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/)